Adding continuous number starting with 0.000 to end of the QGIS Attribute table
I want to add a serial number starting from 0.000 to the attribute table using the field calculator. How can implement it?

You simply want to add a row number? 1, 2, 3, ...

Do you want to increase the number by steps of 0.001? So 0.001, 0.002, ... And is the row order fixed?

Variant 1: In the order of the features
Create a new field using the Field Calculator and this expression:
(@row_number - 1)/1000

This creates intervals of 0.001. Change the number of 1000 to create other intervals. This creates increasing values in the order the features are saved (the order in which they were initially created).
Variant 2: In an order based on attribute values
If you want to get the numbers based on another sort order, based on the content of an attribute field (here: id_new), use this expression:
(array_find(array_sort(array_agg(id_new)), id_new))/1000

Left: variant 1, right: variant 2

